# error using include_once with a php variable

Tags: php

```
//$GLOBAL_includesPath = "http://localhost/smthing/";

    <?
       include_once $GLOBAL_includesPath.'global_menu.php';
    ?>
```

error:

> Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: http:// wrapper is
>   disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\smthing\includes\page_header.php on line 39
>
> Warning:
>   include_once(http://localhost/sthing/includes/global_menu.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper
>   could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\smthing\includes\page_header.php on
>   line 39
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'http://localhost/smthing/includes/global_menu.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\smthing\includes\page_header.php on line 39

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trust me, you **do not want to include from URLs**.

- As soon as it's not localhost, it's a huge security risk
- Including a remote PHP file will include its *output*; the PHP code itself will execute on the remote server
- If you want the output, use curl or `file_get_contents()`

If you don't care and just want it to work (bad!), the error told you all you need: Eenable `allow_url_include` in your php.ini.

Otherwise, use `include_once('path/to/your/file/global_menu.php');`

Answer (score 4):

including HTTP urls makes very little sense. Are you **sure** you want to include your **files** this way?

try this one instead

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/smithing/global_menu.php';
```

Comment: thanx for your answer. but seems not working for me. just curious, why i cant do it $GLOBAL_includesPath.'global_menu.php' (whether my $GLOBAL_includesPath is http or file directory)

Comment: why? you can, as long as  $GLOBAL_includesPath points to a local file. I used DOCUMENT_ROOT only because I have no idea what is the path to your document root and this variable usually contains it.