# Cannot call `require()` with absolute paths (`allow_url_include` is set to `0` in PHP.ini)

Tags: include, relative-path, php, absolute-path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error using include_once with a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034064/error-using-include-once-with-a-php-variable)

My code is like this:

```
<?php   // file location: include/config.php
    $CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["HTMLINC"] = "http://127.0.0.1/mysite/html_include";
?>
```

,

```
<?php   // file location: ./template.php
    require_once("include/config.php");
    // ...
    require($CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["HTMLINC"] . "/anotherpage.php"); // Doesn't work
?>
```

It gives the following warning message:

> Warning: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in...

I'm currently testing the code in my local server, so I can easily change the value of `allow_url_include`. But I will eventually upload this code to a remote server. I cannot guaranty that `allow_url_include` will always be set to `1`.

How do I prevent this warning message and make this code work?

Comment: Please **DON'T** do that. Include file from filesystem

Comment: @zerkms: Oh, I understand the idea now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that isn't an absolute path. that is a URL. the absolute path would be the path to the file on disk. If you go to `/var/www/mysite/html_include` to access the file to edit it, that is the absolute path. You would want to set `$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["HTMLINC"]` to that absolute path. You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the web root supplied by apache and append the `/mysite/html_include` to generate the right path. ideally you would probably have a separate config variable called something like APP_ROOT that is the document root + /mysite (the absolute path to your application). something like:

```
<?php
$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["APP_ROOT"] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite';
$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["HTMLINC"] = $CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["APP_ROOT"].'/html_include';
```

This would allow you to use APP_ROOT for other variables too:

```
$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["UPLOADS"] = $CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["APP_ROOT"].'/uploads';
$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["IMAGES"] = $CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["APP_ROOT"].'/images';
$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["THUMBNAILS"] = $CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["APP_ROOT"].'/thumbs';
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use http URLs as your includes - they won't work the way you expect anyway.

If they are enabled, they will be treated as external URLs, and thus parsed by PHP before being served to the including page. The resulting output will therefore not include any PHP code because it will already have been executed.

If you want to include a local file, you need to provide a directory path on the local disk, not a URL (not even a localhost URL).

In any case, the ability to run includes from a URL is virtually always disabled by any sane hosting company because it is a massive security risk to allow code to come in from a third party site and be run directly on your system.

If you want to include a file local to the web site, you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to reference the root of the site, or `__DIR__` to reference the directory of the current file. I guess the former would be best in your case, so you need this:

```
$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["HTMLINC"] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysite/html_include";
```

hope that helps.

Comment: If you need a remote file to be parsed by the remote system, and then to "include" (but not `include()` ) that content, try `echo file_get_contents($remote_path);` That way you get the benefits without the risk.

Answer (score 1):

You put in a URL by using "http://127.0.0.1". You must reference it from the file system, not by local IP. So you need to set `$CONFIG["DIRECTORY"]["HTMLINC"] = '/path/from/root/html_include'`

"Absolute paths" in file systems are not like absolute paths in HTML (which begin with the protocol - i.e 'http://').