# Require_once and fopen in php security

Tags: php, fopen, require-once

I have 1 file that i've implemented in PHP. 
Error that i get is

**Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/catalog/view/theme/default/template/payment/bank_transfer.tpl on line 13Warning:**

Questions:

1. I know that i need to fix this by allowing allow_url_include=0, in php.ini.I'm using MAMP, i've searched all the folders in MAMP and MAMP Pro, but i didn't find any line, where i can set that value to 0. **Do i add this line?**
2. I've read [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034064/error-using-include-once-with-a-php-variable) and i'm worried that there are some security issues with using require_once, fopen and absolute URL. Is there any security issues with using absolute URL and require_once?
3. How can i specify URL to the document? Currently it's **www.example.com/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php**, i tried to use relative URL **/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php**, but i didn't find the file. Am i doing it right?

bank_transfer.tpl:

```
<h2><?php echo $text_instruction; ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
          <p><?php echo $text_description; ?></p>
          <p><?php echo $bank; ?></p>
          <p><?php echo $text_payment; ?></p>
          <p><?php echo $orderIdKZM; ?></p>
          <p>
          <?php 
            echo $amountKZM; 
            $titleKZM = $titleKZM.$orderIdKZM; 
            echo '<br>';

            require_once('http://example.com/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php');
            echo $titleKZM;
            echo '<br>';

            $merchantIdKZM = '10';
            $currencyKZM = 'KZT';
            $successUrlKZM = 'http://localhost:8888/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm_pay.php';
            $erroUrlKZM = 'http://www.google.com';

            $dateKZM = " ";
            $signstrKZM = " ";
            $verKZM = " ";
            echo $merchantIdKZM.'-'.$currencyKZM.'-'.$successUrlKZM.'-'.$erroUrlKZM.'-'.$dateKZM;

          ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="right">
            <form action="/opencart/testkzm.php" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="merchantIdKZM" value="<?php echo $merchantIdKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="orderIdKZM" value="<?php echo $orderIdKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="amountKZM" value="<?php echo $amountKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="currencyKZM" value="<?php echo $currencyKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="successUrlKZM" value="<?php echo $successUrlKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="errorUrlKZM" value="<?php echo $errorUrlKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="signstrKZM" value="<?php echo $signstrKZM; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="verKZM"  value="<?php echo $verKZM; ?>">

                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" class="button" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "i tried to use relative URL /opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php" - this is neither a URL (it is a path), and it also is not relative, it is absolute. So unless this exact path to the file exists on your server, it will fail. Learn the difference between a file path (accessed via the filesystem) and a URL (accessed via network protocols like HTTP).

Comment: fwiw, `require_once` (like `echo`) is a statement, not a function and  does not require that it the argument list be surrounded by `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changing allow_url_include=1 is not safe.** It's set to disabled by default.

When I include something on the local machine I always use something like this so it can be ported across platforms. Hardcoding an include below the web root can lead to mandatory rewrites if you're on a shared hosting plan or if you don't control your server. Also this is more portable for a dev/production environment.

```
<?php

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php');

?>
```

If you need to get to another directory you can always do something like this:

```
<?php

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../website2_folder/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php');

?>
```

Comment: 'Hardcoding an include below the web root can lead to mandatory rewrites'. So if i use code that you suggested, it will lead to mandatory rewrites?

Comment: No. If you use for instance include('/var/www/includes/file.php') and moved to a server with a different structure like /www/includes then you would have to go into every file and search for the code to change all of the includes. Whereas $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] would be /var/www on server 1 and /www on server 2.

Answer (score 1):

You should give require_once() path relative to a filesystem, not site URL.

For example you have site `http://example.com` and scripts for this site located in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` directory. So, you should use `require_once("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php");` instead of `require_once('http://example.com/opencart/admin/kzm/kzm.utils.php');`.

And no config modification is needed in that case.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 questions i don't know

3) If php code which you want require is your current directory, try this:

```
require_once("kzm.utils.php");
```

If doesnt, use full path 
Example:

require_once("/var/www/opencart/kzm.utils.php);